# why is setState not working correctly with setTimeout?

Tags: reactjs, state, settimeout, setstate, react-functional-component

I am having trouble with setState in a functional component in react. I am trying to build a sort visualizer with react. My functional component has a state property called array which is an array of random numbers, with that array I am creating an array of "Bars" which are divs styled and displaying them on the screen.

In the handleClick() function in my component I am creating a copy of the array stored in state and in each iteration I am swapping values on that copy. My problem is that after I swapped those values in the copy I am trying to use setArray to update the array to the new version of copy with the values swapped but this isn't working. I am attempting to change both tempArray and array inside a timeout because I need a delay between each swap. tempArray is correctly changing in each iteration but array isn't changing at all.

I believe this is enough information for understanding the issue but in case you need more context I added it after the code.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function DisplayVector() {
  let [array, setArray] = useState(vector);

  let vectorBars = array.map((num, index) => {
    let height = `${num * 2}%`;
    let width = `${90 / vector.length}%`;
    return <Bar key={index} width={width} height={height}></Bar>;
  });

  function handleClick() {
    let [comparisions, swaps] = bubble_Sort(array);
    let tempArr = [...array];
    for (let i = 0; i < comparisions.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        let [firstIndex, secondIndex] = comparisions[i];
        if (swaps[i]) {
          [tempArr[firstIndex], tempArr[secondIndex]] = [
            tempArr[secondIndex],
            tempArr[firstIndex],
          ];
        }
        setArray(tempArr);
      }, i * 1000);
    }
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Wrapper>{vectorBars}</Wrapper>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>touch me</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

When the button on the functional component is clicked calls the function handleClick(). This function calls bubbleSort that returns an array conformed by two arrays. The first one is called comparisions and it's conformed by arrays containing the indexes corresponding to all the comparisions that bubbleSort did while sorting the algorithm (e.g. [1,2],[2,3] and so on for every par of indexes that bubbleSort compared). The second one contains booleans where each boolean corresponds to a par of indexes that bubbleSort commpared, if the boolean it's true it means that the indexes have to be swapped, if it's false they don't have to be swapped. I debbuged the handleClick function with dev tools and I found that tempArray is actually swapping the values in the iterations that swap is true but setArray(tempArray) isn't working correctly and the array in state isn't changing at all.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Basically that tempArray is changing with each iteration and although I am setting array to be equal to tempArray in each iteration this is not working. So the value of array isn't changing